# Invalid block tag on line 2: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %} Home {% endblock %} {% block content
%} {% endblock %}
```

Seems correct to me, but it's showing this error.

[image]

Comment: One of your block tag is split over two lines. `{% block content %}` should entirely be on one line. (Also I don't really understand your aversion of newlines, I'd have added a newline after `{% extends "base.html" %}` and each block would have started on a newline as well)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It was my prettier extension in VSCode